How to auto scroll vertically and also horizontally toward the mouse pointer?
I am using react-bubble-ui this package.
import BubbleUI from "react-bubble-ui";
import "react-bubble-ui/dist/index.css";
import Child from "./ChildComponent";
import "./bees_bubble.css";

export default function Bubbles({ bees }) {
  const options = {
    size: 65,
    minSize: 20,
    gutter: 10,
    provideProps: true,
    numCols: 25,
    fringeWidth: 10,
    fringeHeight: 10,
    yRadius: 100,
    xRadius: 100,
    cornerRadius: 50,
    showGuides: false,
    compact: true,
    gravitation: 5,
  };

  const children = bees?.map((data: any, i: number) => {
    return <Child data={data} key={i} />;
  });

  return (
    <BubbleUI options={options} className="h-[300px] rounded-50">
      {children}
    </BubbleUI>
  );
}

I achieved the desired look. But the problem is that I can't move horizontally. Mouse wheel only scrolls to vertical direction. I want to scroll it to where the mouse pointer is. I could not isolate the affect only to this component.
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import BubbleUI from "react-bubble-ui";
import "react-bubble-ui/dist/index.css";
import Child from "./ChildComponent";
import "./bees_bubble.css";

export default function Bubbles({ bees }) {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const bubbleContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const options = {
    size: 65,
    minSize: 20,
    gutter: 10,
    provideProps: true,
    numCols: 25,
    fringeWidth: 10,
    fringeHeight: 10,
    yRadius: 100,
    xRadius: 100,
    cornerRadius: 50,
    showGuides: false,
    compact: true,
    gravitation: 5,
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    if (!bubbleContainerRef.current) return;

    // Get the dimensions of the bubble container
    const containerRect = bubbleContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const containerCenterX = containerRect.left + containerRect.width / 2;
    const containerCenterY = containerRect.top + containerRect.height / 2;

    // Calculate the distance from the mouse pointer to the center of the bubble container
    const offsetX = (e.clientX - containerCenterX) * 0.1; // Scale movement for smoother transition
    const offsetY = (e.clientY - containerCenterY) * 0.1; // Scale movement for smoother transition

    // Update the position state to move the bubbles
    setPosition((prevPosition) => ({
      x: prevPosition.x + offsetX,
      y: prevPosition.y + offsetY,
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, []);

  const children = bees?.map((data: any, i: number) => (
    <Child data={data} key={i} />
  ));

  return (
    <div
      ref={bubbleContainerRef}
      className="myBubbleUI h-[300px] rounded-50"
      style={{
        transform: `translate(${position.x}px, ${position.y}px)`,
        transition: "transform 0.1s ease-out", // Smooth out the movement
      }}
    >
      <BubbleUI options={options} className="h-full w-full">
        {children}
      </BubbleUI>
    </div>
  );
}

I kinda worked out to this but the problem is that it moves the entire div not the bubbles :')
Is there any way that I can make nested div to scroll to mouse pointer direction?
